# Email relaying and email limits

Tags: email, governorlimits, email-relay

According to the [documentation](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_email_general.htm&language=en_US) there is a limit of 1000 emails per day if sent from APEX or API.

If I had configured an [email relay](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_relay.htm&language=en), would sending out an email from APEX count towards the email limit again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Activating email relaying will not remove the limits on mass email.
>
> The reason for this is that the salesforce.com email servers still
>   process the email and thus the bulk load is still on SFDC side. Once
>   processed the email is then passed (or relayed) to your email server
>   before sending.
>
> These limits are enforced so that the load does not become too large
>   for sfdc servers to handle and cause performance issues for other
>   customers

Source : [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gnGBAAY)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make yourself Unlimited while **sending or scheudling the Mass Emails** in **Salesfroce** or doing single emails to Contacts, Leads, sending emails to Campaign Members then you need to check an appexchange native app – Massmailer.This will let you bypass salesforce mass email limits and at the same time let you send simple marketing emails to Schedule one-off mass emails.
Check out the following link: MassMailer App Link on AppExchange
[enter link description here](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000005uxj5EAA)